# Função calcula data e retorna invalid date

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```js
 //função exibe data de hoje no campo cancelamento
   function Data(){
            data = new Date();
            dia = data.getDate();
            mes = data.getMonth()+1;
            ano = data.getFullYear();
            if (dia <10){
              dia ='0'+dia;
            }
           if (mes <10){
              mes ='0'+mes; 
            }
           dataCompleta = dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;
      
            return dataCompleta;
        }
        
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("cancelamento").value = Data();
        }
        function calculaData(){
   var adesao = new Date (document.retencao.adesao.value);
   var cancelamento = new Date (document.retencao.cancelamento.value);
   var meses = adesao - cancelamento;
   document.getElementById("tempo").value = meses;
   }
        function calculaParcela(){
       var individual = parseFloat(document.retencao.individual.value);
       var dependente = parseFloat(document.retencao.dependente.value);
       var parcela = individual * dependente;
       document.getElementById("parcela").value = parcela.toFixed(2) ; 
       }
       
       function calculaInvestimento(){
    var vparcela = parseFloat(document.retencao.parcela.value);
    alert("parcela recebida")
    var tempo = parseFloat(document.rentencao.tempo.value);
    alert("recebeu valor do tempo")
    var investimento = vparcela * tempo;
    document.getElementById("investimento").value = investimento.toFixed(2) ;           
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title> Retenção </title>
<script language="javascript" src="javascript/funcoes.js"> </script> 
</head>
  <body>
    <form name="retencao" >
 <fieldset>
 <legend >Calculo de Investimento</legend>
 <label>Adesão</label>
 <input type="date" id="adesao" name="adesao" required="required" oninput="calculaData()">  
 <!--pega a data de adesão do beneficiario--> 
 <label>Cancelamento</label>
 <input type="text" id="cancelamento" name="cancela" readonly="readonly" size="8" onload="calculaData()">
 <!--data de cancelamento do beneficiario pega a data atual--> 
 <label>Planos</label>
 <select id="seletor" size="1" required="required" name="seletor">
 <!--Para o seletor de planos pensei em um imput select, com a seleção do plano por esse imput preciso 
 que o valor seja retornado no imput individual-->
 <option selected="selected" value="">Selecione o plano</option>
 <option value="29.90">Fundamental</option>  
 </select>
 <label>Dependentes</label>
 <!--Aqui sera informado a quantidade de beneficiarios para calculo no valor da  parcela-->
 <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" id="depedente" name="dependente" required="required" onchange="calculaParcela()">
 <br>  
 <label>Tempo de plano</label>
 <!--Este imput deve receber o resultado de uma conta dos campos adesão e cancelamento da seguinte
 forma =cancelmamento - adesão e retornar a quantidade de meses que o beneficiario permaneceu com o 
 plano -->
 <input type="text" name="tempo" id="tempo" size="10" readonly="readonly" onchange="calculaInvestimento()" >
 <label>Individual</label>
 <!--Recebe valor artibuido ao select com o valor do plano-->
 <input type="text" id="individual" name="individual" size="10" oninput="calculaParcela()" onchange="calculaInvestimento()"  > 
 <label>Parcela</label>
 <!--Parcela recebe a quantidade de dependentes vezes o valor individual-->
 <input type="text" name="parcela" id="parcela" size="10" onchange="calculaInvestimento()">
 <label>Investimento</label>
 <!--Investimento deve mutiplicar a quantidade de meses vezes o valor da parcela para retorno do valor
 investido durante o tempo que o beneficiario permaneceu com o plano-->
 <input type="text" name="investimento" id="investimento" readonly="readonly" size="10">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Calcular">  
 </fieldset>    
    </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Porém a conta que tentei fazer com as datas dizem que elas estão inválidas. Alguém pode me ajudar dizendo-me o que está errado?

Comment: Não estou dizendo que o erro é por causa disso, porém é bom saber: O evento `oninput` é semelhante ao `onchange`. A diferença é que o evento `oninput` ocorre imediatamente após o valor de um elemento ter mudado, enquanto `onchange` ocorre quando o elemento perde o foco, depois que o conteúdo foi alterado.

Comment: Não quero dizer que com essa indicação deste post vc deva aceitar minha resposta.
 https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 -  oninput="calculaData()"

O evento `oninput` é semelhante ao `onchange`. A diferença é que o evento `oninput` ocorre imediatamente após o valor de um elemento ter mudado, enquanto `onchange` ocorre quando o elemento perde o foco, depois que o conteúdo foi alterado.

Retirei esse evento do input `adesao` e coloquei o evento  `onsubmit` na tag form do formulário.  `<form name="retencao" onsubmit="calculaData()">`

2 - O input type=date  `adesao` apesar de se digitar no campo no formato dd/mm/aaaa no javascript ele entra no formato americano, ou seja, aaaa-mm-dd.

3 - A data do input type=text  `cancelamento` está no formato dd/mm/aaaa e entra no javascript nesse formato.

Portanto há que se formatar a string vindo do input `cancelamento` para um formato válido de data, ou seja, aaaa-mm-dd

> **Alterações no script:** um formato de data para efeito de calculo e outro para visualização

```
 window.onload = function(){
    /formato para calculo
    document.getElementById("cancelamento").value = Data();
    //formato para visualização
    document.getElementById("visualiza").value = dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;; 
 }
```

**SCRIPT COMPLETO**

```
    //função exibe data de hoje no campo cancelamento

        var dia, mes,ano;

        function Data(){
            data = new Date();
            dia = data.getDate();
            mes = data.getMonth()+1;
            ano = data.getFullYear();
                if (dia <10){
              dia ='0'+dia;
            }
            if (mes <10){
              mes ='0'+mes; 
            }
            dataCompleta = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;

            return dataCompleta;
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            //formato para calculo
            document.getElementById("cancelamento").value = Data();
            //formato para visualização
            document.getElementById("visualiza").value = dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;; 
        }

    /*função calcula a data com base nos inputs adesão e cancelamento e deve retornar a diverença entre eles em meses*/
        function calculaData(){
            var adesao = new Date (document.retencao.adesao.value);
            var cancelamento = new Date (document.retencao.cancelamento.value);

            var timeDiff = Math.abs(cancelamento.getTime() - adesao.getTime());
            //retorno em dias
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
            alert("A diferença em dias é " + diffDays);         

        }
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="retencao" onsubmit="calculaData()">
    <fieldset>
    <legend >Calculo de Investimento</legend>
    <label>Adesão</label>
    <input type="date" id="adesao" name="adesao" required="required">  
    <!--pega a data de adesão do beneficiario-->    
    <label>Cancelamento</label>
    <!--data do cancelamento simples visualizaçao-->
    <input style="display:none" type="text" id="cancelamento" name="cancelamento" onload="calculaData()">
    <!--data de cancelamento do beneficiario pega a data atual-->
    <input type="text" id="visualiza" name="visualiza" readonly="readonly" size="8">
    <label>Planos</label>
    <select id="seletor" size="1" required="required" name="seletor">
    <!--Para o seletor de planos pensei em um imput select, com a seleção do plano por esse imput preciso 
    que o valor seja retornado no imput individual-->
    <option selected="selected" value="">Selecione o plano</option>
    <option value="29.90">Fundamental</option>      
    </select>
    <label>Dependentes</label>
    <!--Aqui sera informado a quantidade de beneficiarios para calculo no valor da  parcela-->
    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" id="depedente" name="dependente" required="required" onchange="Parcela()">
    <br>        
    <label>Tempo de plano</label>
    <!--Este imput deve receber o resultado de uma conta dos campos adesão e cancelamento da seguinte
    forma =cancelmamento - adesão e retornar a quantidade de meses que o beneficiario permaneceu com o 
    plano -->
    <input type="text" name="tempo" id="tempo" size="10" >
    <label>Individual</label>
    <!--Recebe valor artibuido ao select com o valor do plano-->
    <input type="text" id="individual" name="individual" size="10" >    
    <label>Parcela</label>
    <!--Parcela recebe a quantidade de dependentes vezes o valor individual-->
    <input type="text" name="parcela" id="parcela" size="10" onchange="Investimento()">
    <label>Investimento</label>
    <!--Investimento deve mutiplicar a quantidade de meses vezes o valor da parcela para retorno do valor
    investido durante o tempo que o beneficiario permaneceu com o plano-->
    <input type="text" name="investimento" id="investimento" readonly="readonly" size="10">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calcular">      
    </fieldset>     
</form>>
```

Comment: fiz algumas alterações no código e to bem perto do efeito desejado pra esse código conforme o os comentários em html e no javascript vou atualizar meu código pra vocês continuarem me ajudando, referente a sua sugestão achei interessante mas pretendo colocar outro script la que sera o calcula investimento

Comment: como faço pra data entrar  no formato valido pra calculo Leo Caracciolo

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda problema resolvido

Comment: mas ja podemos dar por resolvido agora tenho outro problema mais to impedido de fazer novas perguntas por 24 hrs num fui la muito bem sucedido na primeira rsrs